# AngularJs $mddialog how to reload the content in templateurl everytime I click it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Every time I clicked the button that executes $scope.showAdvanced, the content of the mddialog remain the same even though I have changed the content of the post.html. I try even clear cache (shift+f5) but the content remain the old one.

```
var CardAng=angular.module('CardAng',['ngMaterial','ngMessages']);


    CardAng.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$mdDialog){

        $scope.imagePath="img/IMG1.jpg";


        $scope.showAdvanced = function(ev) {
            $mdDialog.show({
              controller: DialogController,
              templateUrl: '/post.html',
              parent: angular.element(document.body),
              targetEvent: ev,
              clickOutsideToClose:true,
              fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
            })
            .then(function(answer) {
              $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
            }, function() {
              $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
            });
          };

     function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {

        $scope.hide = function() {
          $mdDialog.hide();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
          $mdDialog.cancel();
        };

        $scope.answer = function(answer) {
          $mdDialog.hide(answer);
        };
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS has own `$templateCache`.
Try to clear it.

`$templateCache.remove('/post.html')` or `$templateCache.removeAll();`

Comment: is that any method can clear the cache or update the template without refresh (f5)?

Comment: this cache does not require f5. Just clear target template before displaying it. Be carefull, browser can cache it, so you should provide appropriate backend cache headers